# VSTO - Delete an attendee/recipient from Meeting invite C#

Tags: c#, plugins, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to delete/remove an attendee/recipient from meeting invite 
When using **recipients[i].Delete()** method, it will remove the recipient from "the recipient list" and he will not receive the invitation. BUT the sender still sees the deleted email addresses on the invite. It does not remove from the "invitation view"
I am not sure how to remove it from "invitation view" too
I am using the same logic when deleting a recipient from mailitem and it works there

Comment: Are you removing the recipient from the ongoing MeetingItem object?Or from the parent AppointmentItem object?

Comment: I am using Outlook.Recipient.Delete()

Comment: And what does Outlook variable point to? MeetingItem object? Or an AppointmentItem object? Where does it come from?

Comment: MeetingItem object

Answer (score 0):

Call `MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(false)`, and if it returns a nun-null `AppointmentItem` object, remove the recipient from its `Recipients` collection as well.